# How do I turn off the programs on my White Rodgers thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I can't find anything on the internet about this issue. Sites like this: https://www.hunker.com/12279552/how-to-program-a-white-rogers-thermostat
explain how to set up a program but they don't explain how to turn off programs.

Comment: What model is your thermostat?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. It came with the condo when I purchased it and there was no manual. It's fairly recent though (~2015/2016).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thermostats are *always* running a program, and you can adjust the times & temperatures (varies a lot, but typical is 4 changes per day x 7 days per week) but can't actually say "don't run any program". In that case you generally have two options:

#### Override/Hold

Most thermostats I have worked with have a "override" or "hold" setting, typically by pressing & holding a particular button for a couple of seconds and then adjusting the temperature. In some cases, the "hold" is set & forget. In others, there are two "levels" of "hold" - temporary and permanent (but terminology may vary, or one may be "override" and one "hold", etc.). With a "temporary" hold, at the next program set time, the program resumes. With a "permanent" hold, the hold stays until you manually release the hold or change the thermostat mode (e.g., heat vs. cool).

#### Constant Program

Let's say you want 72 degrees all the time. Set the thermostat program for each day:

- 6:00am 72
- 9:00am 72
- 5:00pm 72
- 10:00pm 72

The thermostat will continue to cycle through the program - doing exactly what you want!

One other problem you might find:

#### Occupied/Unoccupied

I had a commercial customer years ago that wanted constant 72 degrees since their offices and/or warehouse were in nearly constant use (midnight to 7pm or longer) and they didn't want to worry about people coming in at different times and finding the place too hot or cold. But they *also* wanted the fan running all the time to keep from feeling "stale" when the ambient temperature didn't require much actual heating or cooling. But the fan would only run 1/2 the time (plus when the heating or cooling was actually running). **The HVAC people couldn't figure it out.**

It was actually quite simple. I read the poorly written manual and figured it out: The programs (which could not be turned off) alternated between *occupied* and *unoccupied*. In *unoccupied* mode, the fan would **NOT** run constantly, even if set as "On" instead of "Auto"! The solution was quite simple: I changed the times of the programs so that *unoccupied* was 2 15-minute chunks (smallest possible) at odd times of the day (so as to affect the fewest people). Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a White Rogers 1F78, returning it to manual is fairly simple.  I just did it on ours.  You must hold 3 buttons simultaneously: the time button, and both the up and down temperature arrows. Zeros will flash across the screen. Hold several seconds and when you release them, there will no longer be the time displayed and you will have returned to manual.  You will no longer have the ability to display time on the screen. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.